# multi processor programming - badclhlock

Tags: multiprocessing

This code implements an alternative implementation of CLHLock in which
a thread reuses its own node instead of its predecessor node. How this
implementation can go wrong ?

```
public class BadCLHLock implements Lock {
// most recent lock holder
AtomicReference<Qnode> tail;
// thread-local variable
ThreadLocal<Qnode> myNode;
public void lock() {
    Qnode qnode = myNode.get();
    qnode.locked = true;
    // I’m not done
    // Make me the new tail, and find my predecessor
    Qnode pred = tail.getAndSet(qnode);
    // spin while predecessor holds lock
    while (pred.locked) {}
}
public void unlock() {
    // reuse my node next time
    myNode.get().locked = false;
}
static class Qnode { // Queue node inner class
    public boolean locked = false;
}
```

}

Comment: Text book questions from The Art of Multiprocessor Programming, Exercise 85.

Answer (score 2):

If thread A runs lock(), unlock() then lock() again then 
when

```
Qnode pred = tail.getAndSet(qnode);
```

is executed qnode and pred will be referencing the same node, thus
pred.locked will always be true.

So, if myNode = A from the start, after the first lock()
also tail = A. now when we run lock() again we first set
A.locked = true, set pred = tail (pred = A) and wait for A.locked to turn true which will not happen.

-This is exercise 85 in "The art of multiprocessor programming" by Herlihy & Shavit

Answer (score 1):

- Let's T1, T2 be two concurrent threads.
- Let's QN1, QN2 be QNodes of each thread respectively.

Deadlock Scenario:

1. T1 and T2 never acquired the lock:

   ```
   Tail -> Null
   ```
2. T1 acquires the lock

   ```
   Tail -> QN1(true)
   ```
3. T2 try to acquire the lock, but because T1 have it, must wait

   ```
   Tail -> QN2(true) -> QN1(true)
   ```
4. T1 releases the lock

   ```
   Tail -> QN2(true) -> QN1(false)
   ```
5. But before, T2 check QN1 had release the lock, T1 try to reacquire it.

   ```
   Tail -> QN1(true) -> QN2(true) -> QN1(true)
   ```
6. Because QN2 points to QN1 as its predecessor, and QN1 knows nothing about.
   QN2 thinks that QN1 still holds the lock, and QN1 have to wait QN2 release it.

Deadlock condition happen and nobody will be able to acquire the lock.